# Is there a proper way to create a multi-step animation triggered by mouseover and mouseleave events?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have the following code.

https://codepen.io/cedrictalves/pen/zYeVpmy

```
<body>
  <a class="one link" href="#a-propos">
  <span>about</span>
  <div class="up"></div>
  <div class="down"></div>
  </a>
</body>
```

```
<style>
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.notransition{
  transition: none !important;
}

a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

a:hover{
  color: white;
}
span{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.up{
   display: block;
   width: 0;
   height: calc(50% + 10px);
   border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: blue;
   transition: width 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
   transform-origin: left;
   top: -10px;
   left: -15px;
   opacity: 0;
}
.down{
   display: block;
   width: 0;
   height: calc(50% + 10px);
   border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: red;
   transition: width 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
   transform-origin: right;
   bottom: -10px;
   right: -15px;
   opacity: 0;
}



.hovered .up{
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.hovered.leaved{
  pointer-events: none;
}

.hovered.leaved .up{
  opacity: 0;
  top: -30px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1), top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1), height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);          
}
.hovered .down{
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.hovered.leaved .down{
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: -30px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1), top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1), height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);          
}
</style>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.link').on('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    });
  
    $('.link').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).addClass('leaved');
        setTimeout(() => {
            $(this).removeClass('hovered leaved');
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(() => {
            $(this).removeClass('notransition');
        }, 600);
    });

});
```

As you can see, there is a mouseover animation and a mouseleave one.

If I mouseover again before the mouse leave animation triggers, the mouseover doesn't transition smoothly. Do any of you have an idea about how to make it work fine?

Thank you all! :)

Comment: The mouse over transition works well only when it happens from no state to `hovered` state. This doesn't happen when mouse leave is in progress. I suggest you use CSS [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#applying_multiple_animations) instead of `transition`. In case of `animation` start and end states are always predefined.

Comment: It works fine like that, you're right! thank's a lot!